# Angular2 activatedRoute queryParam get undefined param from subscribe

Tags: angular

In my component, in ngOnInit, I have a subscribe to activedRoute.queryParam to get query parameters. But sometimes it gets undefined values which break the subsequent API calls since the undefined gets passed into the API.

```
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {     
        this.personId = params['personId'];
    });
```

How should I make sure I get the personId first before I make API calls.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You talk about queryParams, but in your code you use params

Comment: sry, it's queryParams. I just corrected the post. @ Noémi Salaün

Comment: In your case, personId can be undefined only if not present in the URL. If you can have the case when personId is not defined, you have to check if it is defined before calling the API (see @callback answer). If you don't want personId to be optional, maybe you should use params instead of queryParams and have your URL looking like /my/:persondId/url instead of /my/url?personId=xxx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [filter operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/filter.html) as follows to make sure you subscribe only when the value exists:

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.filter(params => params['personId'])
.subscribe(params => {     
   this.personId = params['personId'];
   // make your other API calls..   

});
```

Comment: yes, filter operator works for me.  this.sub = this.activatedRoute.queryParams.filter(params => params['personId'] ).distinctUntilChanged().subscribe(params => {     
        this. personId = params['personId'];
        //api calls
        
 });